# Swagger UI -- No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: java, cors, http-headers, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm writing an API in Java, and using Swagger to document it. However, when I attempt to "Try It Out" in Swagger, I get a prompt that reads:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have added headers to my endpoints, and it works for some of them, but not all of them.

```
Response.noContent()
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD")
                .build();
```

OR

```
Response.ok(results)
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD")
                .build();
```

Has anyone experienced this? Any solve?

Comment: Is that response being built on an OPTIONS request?

Comment: The response is being built on a GET request.

Comment: Typically, browsers send an OPTIONS request just to check the headers, it's then that they generate this type of error. So you need to also do that in an `@OPTIONS` method (depending on your framework).

Comment: The thing is, adding these headers to some of the endpoints works fine with Swagger UI, and I no longer get the error. But with other endpoints, I do get the error. I don't understand the inconsistencies.